# Threading Slower than Multiple Notebooks

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to thread multiple read_sql_query commands using Pandas. However, threading in one notebook is drastically slower than simply running each read_sql command in separate notebooks at once.

My threaded code is:

```
SQL_Queries = ["Query 1" , "Query 2" , "Query 3"]
SQL_Results = []

def myfunct(i):
   SQL_Results.append(pd.read_sql_query(SQL_Queries[i]))

for i in range(3):
   t = Thread(target=myfunct, args=(i,))
   t.start()
```

This runs in about 2 minutes. However, if I open up 3 IPython notebooks like the following:

NOTEBOOK 1: `pd.read_sql_query("Query 1")`

NOTEBOOK 2: `pd.read_sql_query("Query 2")`

NOTEBOOK 3: `pd.read_sql_query("Query 3")`

and hit run on each at the same time, they'll all be finished within 1 minute. Any ideas on how I can achieve this performance in one notebook?

Comment: why do you have to use notebooks?

Comment: @MohammadAthar need to share script with coworkers. Notebooks are what they're familiar with

Comment: Have you tried just replacing threading with multiprocessing? If your code is mostly doing CPU-bound work, in Python code or C code that isn’t written to release the GIL, only one thread per process will progress at a time.